# Autohotkey: problem with minimizing windows

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I create two windows through autohotkey and move them to my leftmost and rightmost monitor respectively (I have 3 monitors).
When I minimize them, and call them again, they are being shown on the central monitor. But I want them to be shown where they were before.

See following gif.

[image]

Following is the ahk script:

```
Run, Notepad
WinWait, ahk_class Notepad
WinSetTitle, asd
Run, Notepad
Sleep, 1000
WinGet, fensterID, List, ahk_class Notepad
Loop, %fensterID% { ; will run loop for number of windows in array
  WinActivateBottom, % "ahk_id " fensterID%A_Index%
  WinGetTitle, title, A
  MsgBox, %title%
  if (title == "asd")
    WinMove A,, 1500, 0
  else
    WinMove A,, -2304, 0
  WinMaximize, A
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I switched to AutoIt and - having the same problem there - I found out, thanks also to [this](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/206678-window-not-restored-correctly-after-manual-minimize/?tab=comments#comment-1489519), that it works if I disable the maximized option for Windows Terminal (the actual program I was trying out with), then move and maximize the window. It should do the same with AutoHotKey.